# Powershell console profile aliases (functions) not working, why?

Tags: powershell, alias, windows-10-v1709

[This TechNet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx) says the location of a console profile file for the current user only and all shells shall be:

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\Windows­PowerShell\profile.ps1
```

In my case, the `%UserProfile%` points to:

```
 C:\Users\vlastimil
```

So, I created the following file:

```
C:\Users\vlastimil\Documents\Windows­PowerShell\profile.ps1
```

Which at this very moment contains 2 functions:

```
function sha256sum([string]$arg) {
    (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $arg | Select -ExpandProperty Hash).ToLower()
}

function sha512sum([string]$arg) {
    (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA512 $arg | Select -ExpandProperty Hash).ToLower()
}
```

---

But calling these functions throws an error:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\vlastimil> sha512sum
> sha512sum : The term 'sha512sum' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + sha512sum
> + ~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sha512sum:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

---

As I know very little of Windows, I don't know where the problem is.

---

OS: Windows 10 Pro 1709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile location revealed with:

```
echo $PROFILE
```

> ```
> C:\Users\vlastimil\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
> ```

Thus, after changing the path + name, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference if you are running powershell console, or powershell ISE.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/

Where you put your profile will only work when run from the console. ISE will not see or use this profile.